# Laravel 8 application it does not save data to the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

As in the title, I am developing a web management application with Laravel 8.
In my application I need to upload data from .txt files and keep track of uploads made to the `caricamenti` table whose fields are  `id, file_name, notes, file_path, upload_type, created_at, updated_at`.

`file_name` indicates the name of the uploaded file, example `RA_file.txt`, the `note` field indicates info about the upload and taken from the form I use to perform the import, `file_path` is the path where the file is saved inside of the laravel project and finally `upload_type` indicates the file type `RA, AG, EE, AR`.

When I import RA files I have no error, the data is saved correctly in the appropriate tables and at the end of the import I also get the correct saving of the upload in the `caricamenti` table.

The problem arises with other file types, in fact when I import the data it is correctly saved in the tables, but the `caricamenti` table is not updated.
I did the `dd($caricamenti)` before and after `$caricamenti->save();` and from the `dd` the past data is correct and I can't understand why it doesn't save the upload to the database.

Do I appreciate any suggestions or advice?
Thank you

- MY_CODE:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Caricamenti;
use App\Models\CodiceRaccomandata;
use App\Models\TipoRaccomandata;
use App\Models\TipoServizio;
use App\Models\Raccomandata;
use App\Models\RaccomandataVariabili;
use App\Models\EsitiRaccomandata;
use App\Models\CodiciPrenotazione;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ImportController extends Controller
{

// prendiamo in gestione l'import del file
    public function gestisciImport(Request $request)
    {

        try {

            set_time_limit(-1);

            $validati = $request->validate([
                'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xlsx,txt',
                'note' => 'required',
            ]);

            $file = $request->file('file');
            $base_name = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = $base_name;
            $counter = 1;


            // file con lo stesso nome sono rinominati 'name<n>'in base al numero di volte <n> che il ciclo è eseguito
            // data la diversa estensione dei file customizzo il substr_replace
            while (file_exists(storage_path('uploaded_files/files/') . $name)) {
                $name = substr_replace($base_name, ' (' . $counter++ . ')', (substr($base_name, 0, 2) == 'RA') ? -4 : -4, 0);
            }


            $results = $this->inizializzaImport($request, $request->input('tipo_file'));
            // Salvo sul disco in uploaded_files/files/<nome_file>
            $path = $file->storeAs('files', $name, 'uploadedfiles');
 
            //memorizziamo le info del file nel DB
            $caricamento = new Caricamenti;
 
            $caricamento->nome_file = $name;
            $caricamento->file_path = $path;
            $caricamento->note = $request->input('note');
            $caricamento->tipo_caricamento = $request->input('tipo_file');
            $caricamento->save(); // HERE I'VE THE ERROR AND NOT SAVE
            
            Log::channel('custom_log')->info('L\'utente ' . Auth::user() . ' ha caricato con successo sul DB il file ' . $name . ' ( ' . $file->getSize() . ' bytes )');

            $caricamenti = Caricamenti::get();
            
            return redirect()->back()
                ->with('caricamenti', $caricamenti)
                ->with('results', $results);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            Log::channel('custom_log')->info('L\'utente ' . Auth::user() . ' non è riuscito a caricare sul DB il file ' . $name . ' ( ' . $file->getSize() . ' bytes ) [errore: ' . $e . ']');

            return redirect('/importa')->with('error', 'Non è stato possibile caricare il file ' . $name . ' sul DB!');
        }
    }

 // prendiamo in gestione l'import del tracciato
    public function inizializzaImport(Request $request, $tipo_file)
    {
        // Da sistemare a seconda dei file che dobbiamo importare
        switch ($tipo_file) {
            case 'RA':
                return $this->importRaccomandate($request);
            case 'AG':
                return $this->importEsitiAG($request);
            case 'AR':
                return $this->importEsiti($request);
            case 'EE':
                return $this->importEsiti($request);
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

- EDIT:

For example for the AG files, in the method `salvaEsitiAG($line)` called inside `$this->importEsitiAg($request)` if i comment the if()...elseif() statement, the problem mentioned above disappears.

- salvaEsitiAG($line) code:

```
// funzioni per lo storage della singola riga sul DB  ( Esiti AG )
    private function salvaEsitiAG($line)
    {
     
        DB::beginTransaction();

       // $racc = Raccomandata::select('*')->where('raccomandata.NumeroProgressivoRaccomandata', '=', $line[0])->get()->toArray();
        
       // if(!empty($racc)){

            try {
                $esito = new EsitiRaccomandata;
                
                $esito->id_raccomandata = 1; 
                $esito->numero_cartella = $line[1];
                $esito->nome_file = $line[2];
                $esito->data_ricezione = ($line[3] != "") ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime($line[3])) : null;
                $esito->data_mancata_ricezione = ($line[4] != "") ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime($line[4])) : null;
                $esito->motivo_mancata_ricezione = ($line[5] != "") ? $line[5] : null;
                $esito->scatola  = $line[6];
                $esito->lotto = $line[7];
                $esito->posizione = $line[8];
                $esito->emessoCAD = ($line[9] != "") ? 1 : 0;
                $esito->emessoCAN = ($line[10] != "") ? 1 : 0;
                $esito->visto_arrivare = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($line[11]));
                $esito->errore_poste = $line[12];
                $esito->non_ritirato_10 = ($line[13] != "") ? $line[13] : null;
    
                $esito->save();

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                
                DB::rollBack();

                //aggiungere il LOG dell'evento
                Log::channel('custom_log')->info('Errore nel caricamento dell\'esito relativo la raccomandata con cartella:'.$esito->numero_cartella.' da parte dell\'utente '. Auth::user() .' - errore :'.$e);
                //ritorniamo il messaggio di errore da mostrare nel frontend
                return ['error' => 'Errore nell\'inserimento dell\'esito raccomandata con cartella:'.$esito->numero_cartella.' - controlla l\'esistenza della raccomandata!'];
            }
            
            DB::commit();

            //Loggiamo l'evento
            Log::channel('custom_log')->info('Esito della raccomandata con cartella:'.$esito->numero_cartella.' caricato con successo da parte dell\'utente '. Auth::user());
            //ritorniamo il messaggio di success di corretto inserimento della raccomandata
            return ['success' => 'Esito della raccomandata con numero cartella: '.$esito->numero_cartella.' inserito correttamente nel database'];

      //  }elseif(empty($racc) && !empty($line[0])){
            
             //Loggiamo l'evento
        //     Log::channel('custom_log')->info('Esito della raccomandata con cartella:'.$line[0].' non caricato con successo da parte dell\'utente '. Auth::user().' la raccomandata non esiste sul DB');
             //ritorniamo il messaggio di success di corretto inserimento della raccomandata
        //     return ['warning' => 'Esito della raccomandata con numero cartella: '.$line[0].' non inserito! Controllare l\'esistenza della raccomandata! '];
       //  }
    }
```

Comment: If line `$validati` and `$file = $request->file` works maybe the error is because didn't set `fillable` attribute on `Caricamenti` model. `->save()` will use `id` column, and this use to be a often error, but you said you are have `id`

Comment: Ok, you edited question. And the error is the `DB::commit()`

Comment: Thank's @S.Wasta, i need to remove DB::commit() i think?

Comment: I mean... It's not a error. You are using transactions so you must to commit. `DB::commit()` will save all you transaction, otherwise won't save.

Comment: Thank's...but my `salvaEsitiAG` works well and always save the data in the correct table...the problem always remains in `gestisciImport`.
In the `Caricamenti` model i've assigned `fillable` attributes